# JobScheduler - Schedule Job At Device Bootup?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Is it possible to schedule a job to begin at device bootup using JobScheduler?

Or do I have to use BroadcastReceivers instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience you can only do it using `BroadcastReceiver`. `JobScheduler` are good when you want to run something based on some conditions, not events (actions).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting the `setPersisted(true)` on the `JobInfo` object.

Check the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setPersisted(boolean)).

Keep in mind that you still need the [`RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED) permission though.